# pyplot.scatter(c='red'). Invalid syntax?

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, data-science, scatter

i am a beginner in machine-learning, i've been getting this error for color in pyplot's scatter method, the same error prevails for 's=None' argument as well

```
pyplot.scatter = (X_train, y_train, c = 'red')
pyplot.plot = (X_train, regressor.predict(X_train), c = 'blue')
```

i get this error

```
plt.scatter = (X_train, y_train, c = 'red')
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

how to get rid of this error and when "color = 'red' " was replaced with "c = 'red' "?

Answer (score 2):

You have to remove the `=`:

```
pyplot.scatter(X_train, y_train, c = 'red')
pyplot.plot(X_train, regressor.predict(X_train), c = 'blue')
```

PS.
As convention usually the `matplotlib` library is imported in this way:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.scatter(X_train, y_train, c = 'red')
```